# Listing and editing in a single view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

Suppose I have a `Person` table in my database, and I want a View allows users to edit people like this:

```
All People (Select One)
_______________________
|   Name        Planet
|----------------------
|   Bob         Mars
|   Alice       Venus
-----------------------

Edit Selected Person

Name: _________
Planet: _________
[Submit]
```

Basically, the user is presented with a table containing all people, and below the table is a form that allows the user to edit the selected person (on the same page).

This seems like it would be a common and well-patterned problem.  How would something like this typically be done?

Comment: @DanielA.White, in the edit history of my question I described how I thought it could be done (I took it out, because I thought it polluted the question)... I'm really trying to get at how it *should* be done - not just something that works, but something that is idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML Markup, we can not give a specific answer.

Here is the general idea to do this

Using javascript, get the click event of the row to be selected, Grab the ID (record id) of the record from the Row(assuming you have it there some where in the row). use jQuery ajax to bring the existing data for the record. Show it in a model popup or in a specific part of the existing page (show a hidden div which has input elements so that user can edit the data). When saving, save the data using jQuery ajax.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really looking for a specific solution - just general guidance, like what you have given.